# HashMap: iterating the key-value pairs in random order

Tags: java, data-structures, random, iterator, hashmap

I have a HashMap and I'd like to iterate they key-value pairs in a different random order each time i get the iterator. Conceptually I'd like to "shuffle" the map before calling the iterator (or if you want, "shuffle" the iterator).

I have two options i see:

1) use the approach of LinkedHashMap and keep a list of the entries internally, shuffle it in-place and return that view when the iterator is called.
2) take map.entrySet(), construct an ArrayList and use shuffle() on it.

While the two approaches look vey similar to me, I'm expecting VERY BIG HashMaps, so I'm really concerned on details and internals, as I'm really not in a position to waste memory OR computation.

Comment: You are unaware of the implementation details, but you can always check the java sources... if you are familiar with calculating the time complexity, you should be able to extrapolate something yourself, at least for the computation part :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reshuffling a large collection is always going to be expensive. You are going to need at least one reference per entry. e.g. for 1 million entries you will need approx 4 MB.

Note; the shuffle operation is `O(N)`

I would use

```
Map<K,V> map = 
List<Map.Entry<K,V>> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<K,V>>(map.entrySet());

// each time you want a different order.
Collections.shuffle(list);
for(Map.Entry<K, V> entry: list) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: How is shuffling O(n lg n)? A Fisher-Yates shuffle takes only linear time and so does [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29).

Comment: Correct, A lame sorting shuffle is `O(N * log N)` and the shuffle Java uses is indeed `O(N)`

Comment: This is basically my (2) proposed approach. You rely on the fact that the additional overhead is 4bytes per entry? Why's that?

Comment: Most recent versions of JVMs support 32-bit references. For a large collection most of the space in the list will be the references to the `Map.Entry`s. There is a slight optimisation if you re-shuffle the same list repeatedly.

Comment: In Java 1.7 you can eliminate the explicit type argument  `Map.Entry<K,V>` when making an `ArrayList`. So you can type: `= new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need to shuffle at all:
Just draw a random index in an array of keys and remove the key by overwritting with the last:

```
public class RandomMapIterator<K,V> implements Iterator<V> {

private final Map<K,V> map;
private final K[] keys;

private int keysCount;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public RandomMapIterator(Map<K,V> map) {
    this.map = map;
    this.keys = (K[]) map.keySet().toArray();
    this.keysCount = keys.length;
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    return keysCount!=0;
}

@Override
public V next() {
    int index = nextIndex();
    K key = keys[index];
    keys[index] = keys[--keysCount];
    return map.get(key);
}

protected int nextIndex() {
    return (int)(Math.random() * keysCount);
}

@Override
public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

}

Comment: remove() on an arrayList is not exactly a cheep operation, as it requires shifting of data. also, this requires random access to the data-structure through get(), which is O(1) but still more expensive than iterating internally to the data-structure.

Comment: @marcorossi thanks agree on the `remove()` but my main point remains: Random draw achieves the same purpose as shuffling at a fraction of the cost. `ArrayList` was not the best choice of structure because we do not need keys order to be maintained anyway. I have revised my solution with a simple array. The decision comes down to whether you'd rather take the O(N) cost upfront or O(1) cost on each next().

Answer (score -2):

Try use concurent hash map and get key by random before iteration cycle

```
Map<String, String> map = Maps.newConcurrentMap();

        map.put("1", "1");
        map.put("2", "2");
        Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            map.remove("2");// add random key values
            map.put("2", "2");
            String next = iterator.next();
            System.out.println("next" + next);
        }
```

Random remove/put values can "shuffle" your map

Comment: put can shuffle your entries, but its highly unlikely. remove/put won't do anything.