# How to randomize my Questions using this code?

Tags: android

This code is what I use to make a quiz app... but the problem is I don't know how to make it randomize or shuffle it. I dont know what to change to make it shuffle can you guys help me?

```
package org.intercode.lifeatceu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class levelone extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tv1, tvCred, tvQuestion;
Button btNext;
RadioButton rb1, rb2;
RadioGroup rg;

String questions [] = {"Ma. Cristina D. Padolina is CEU's President", "Carlito B. Olaer is the V.P of CEU", "CEU's VISION is to sting every enemy", "One of CEU's Mission is to promote creative and scholarly academic"};
String answer [] = {"True", "False", "False", "True"};


int flag = 0;
public static int score, correct, wrong, coins;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_levelone);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Intent inquiz = getIntent();
   final int credit = inquiz.getIntExtra("passedCredits", 0);
    String TotalCoins = String.valueOf(credit);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tvCred = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCred);
    tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);
    btNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btNext);


    tvQuestion.setText(questions[flag]);
    tvCred.setText(TotalCoins);

    btNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
            if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(answer[flag]))
            {
                correct++;
                coins++;

            }
            else
            {
                wrong++;
            }
            flag++;
            if (flag < questions.length)
            {
                tvQuestion.setText(questions[flag]);
            }
            else
            {
                score = correct;
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Results.class);
                in.putExtra("passedCredits",credit);
                in.putExtra("passedCorrect",correct);
                in.putExtra("passedWrong",wrong);
                in.putExtra("passedCoins",coins);
                in.putExtra("passedScore",score);
                startActivity(in);
            }

        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Go to github and search the code for quiz app.

Comment: was it same as what i did?..

Comment: bro i think the activities there are too complicated T_T

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HashMap: iterating the key-value pairs in random order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815460/hashmap-iterating-the-key-value-pairs-in-random-order)

Comment: thanks i will try it :D

Comment: @NathanTuggy sir i cannot understand how it actually related to me works... i mean they are wanting to get shuffled items but they its too complicated and i dont know how to use it in my code T_T

Comment: Something like `flag = random.nextInt(4)` before `tvQuestion.setText` should do the job (with `random` being a [`Random`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) instance) **But** you should think about using a `QuizzItem` class holding the question and its answer then use a `List` of `QuizzItem` and `Collections.shuffle`

Answer (score 0):

that HashMap Link given by nathan Tuggy is actually good way to accomplish what you want, but i think you don't familiar with this language..

how about you use like sorting mechanism to change the queue position of your questions at each start of the application, the idea is like this.. (remember not just to copy paste this code, change and add variables as your need)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  String Qtemp;
  String Atemp;
  int switch;
  Random c = new Random();
  Random d = new Random();

        flag= c.nextInt(question.length);
        switch = d.nextInt(question.length);

   Qtemp= question[c]
   Atemp = answer[c]
   question[c] = question[switch];
   answer[c] = answer[switch];
  question[switch] = Qtemp;
  answer[switch] = Atemp; }
```

the idea is like that, just try to make it in a function and call it so your question shuffled at the start of app.

I really do not recommend this way as it not the proper way, but in your case, i just want to show you 'any' way to make the question shuffled.