# get a random value each time the client send request to the server without duplication

Tags: java, hashmap

if I have sentences in hashmap in server.For Example, 5 sentences.The tricky here is the client will use special id for him. the server will use this id to track the sentences that related to the client's id . example :
HashMap in server
sentence 1
sentence 2
sentence 3
sentence 4

when client send request the server will send randomly 
sentence 3
second request 
sentence 4
third request 
sentence 1
fourth request 
sentence 2
until the hashmap randomly completed
if the client send new request so, the server will send new random cycle of sentence

I can't sent
sentence 1
sentence 1
or sentence 1
sentence 2

Comment: and what is the actual question? nice assignment, though.

Comment: get a `Random` int that will `get` the associated indexed value from the underlying Collection

Comment: Wether it is or not an assignment, you have to show a **complete, minimal and verifiable example** of your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the actual question is there a method will help me track the random hashmap and when first random cycle sent to client , start new random cycle .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've already dealt with the singleton nature of the request (by having a single threaded server or by having a synchronized singleton), then you merely need a shuffled array list of keys as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12815460/6664886).

Comment: when using shuffled it will print all sentences together. But if I can copy the shuffled array and start send each sentence to the client when he request.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following with a list.

```
list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
```

`random` must be an instance of `Random`. You should not create multiple ones within a short amount of time to avoid that you get the same random numbers multiple times.

If you want to pick multiple elements and avoid duplicates you can remove a picked element from the list.